# Adding ads in my codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I provide view to advertise ads in my codeigniter application. When client adds ads in my app these adds should display dynamically in my application. If there are 100 people given 100 ads then every time user accesses app he should get different ads on each page refresh. For example if fastrack and Levis are the ads given by clients then these ads must keep changing.

If client who is advertising the product chooses option to publish my add only in india then that ad should published only in  india.

please provide me some link or examples related to my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should try http://www.revive-adserver.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use any free ads server script and integrate it in your app. here you have a list of ten http://www.enfew.com/10-php-advertisement-management-scripts/

you can google for more scripts